# Open HFT Chronicle Map , Class Not Found Exception on Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, chronicle-map

I am trying to use OpenHFT ChronicleMap , the code runs in Tomcat, but fails in Websphere with the following error (below)

Note : This does not happen in Tomcat , only with Websphere.

code :

```
private ChronicleMap<String,RepositoryItem> repositoryMap;

repositoryMap=
            ChronicleMapBuilder
            .of(String.class, RepositoryItem.class).averageKeySize(KEY_SAMPLE.getBytes("UTF-8").length)
            .entries((long) (MAX_ENTRIES))
            .averageValueSize(1600)
            .create();

public void removeAllModified() {
    // This removes all the modified data from the repository
    Iterator iter=repositoryMap.values().iterator();
    // build a list of all the objects in the repository except the removed items
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        RepositoryItem repoItem=(RepositoryItem)iter.next();
        DataObject d = repoItem.getModified();
        if (d != null) {
            removeModified(repoItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this error.

```
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:236 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
[5/30/16 12:45:03:236 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:236 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.lang.io.StringBuilderUtils.<clinit>(StringBuilderUtils.java:36)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:236 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     ... 81 more
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.openhft.lang.io.StringBuilderUtils (initialization failure)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:176)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.lang.io.NativeBytes.readUTF1(NativeBytes.java:173)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.lang.io.NativeBytes.readUTF0(NativeBytes.java:164)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.serialization.internal.CharSequenceReader.read(CharSequenceReader.java:67)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.chronicle.hash.serialization.internal.CharSequenceReader.read(CharSequenceReader.java:31)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap$Segment.getEntry(VanillaChronicleMap.java:3042)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap$EntryIterator.next(VanillaChronicleMap.java:3150)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at net.openhft.chronicle.map.VanillaChronicleMap$EntryIterator.next(VanillaChronicleMap.java:3097)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at java.util.AbstractMap$2$1.next(AbstractMap.java:396)
[5/30/16 12:45:03:267 IST] 0000007a SystemErr     R     at com.csc.fs.om.ObjectRepositoryChronicleImpl.removeAllModified(ObjectRepositoryChronicleImpl.java:1335)
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using? `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder` is part of the runtime since Java 1.5.

Comment: 1.7 (It is throwing this error only with Websphere (IBM JRE). This code works fine in Tomcat.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Lang/blob/master/lang/src/main/java/net/openhft/lang/io/StringBuilderUtils.java

Comment: If you don't run with Oracle JRE maybe using the `IBM JRE` might be the reason. What does `jar tf $JRE_HOME/lib/rt.jar | grep AbstractStringBuilder` return? If it not return `java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.class` than the IBM JRE does not contain this (non-public) class.

Comment: AbstractStringBuilder is not there in the WAS rt.jar. But what is the solution. I cannot replace rt.jar , can I ?

Comment: My production uses Websphere 8.5. and I dont think I can change the WAS runtime to something other than IBM. Can I ?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot answer this question (have no experience with WebSphere). Best you would ask the IBM support.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=e081997a-9f1c-49a4-8fa5-e5032c9647b8&ps=25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronicle Map currently doesn't support the IBM JVM, on which Websphere runs. From your message it's indeed evident, that Chronicle Map 2 fails on the IBM JVM because it occasionally use some classes which are persent in OpenJDK/OracleJDK but absent in the IBM JDK.

Chronicle Map 3 might not have this issue, so potential solution could be to upgrade to Java 8 and Chronicle Map 3. However this would be an incidental property of Chronicle Map 3 and it also could stop working with IBM JVM in any subsequent release.

The releavant discussion in the Chronicle mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-chronicle/cAHVQZLASaE

Comment: Hope this changes !!